# Hibernate: limit in subquery and then sum results

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have a mysql query :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(status_days_count)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        cc.status_days_count
    FROM
        foo cc
    JOIN bar c ON c.id = cc.credit_id
    WHERE
        c.borrower_id = '1'
            AND cc.status = 'EXPIRED'
    ORDER BY cc.calculation_date
    LIMIT 2) AS status_days_count;
```

it works correctly but i need to map it to hibernate criteria or named query, 
but neither in detached criteria, nor in named query i can't use limit, is there a way how to implement it without creating two queries?

Now i came up only with something like this:

```
Criteria lastTwoCredits = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Bar.class);
    lastTwoCredits.addOrder(Order.desc("dateReceived"));
    lastTwoCredits.add(Restrictions.eq("borrowerId", borrowerId));
    lastTwoCredits.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
    lastTwoCredits.setMaxResults(2);
    List<Long> ids = criteriaList(lastTwoCredits);

    Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("credit.borrowerId", borrowerId));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", creditStatus));

    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("creditId", ids));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("statusDaysCount"));

    Object result = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Suggestions how to do it in one query would very appreciated